# why docker does not recognize /bin/sh -c as a valid entrypoint?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a simple nginx container trying to run from docker-compose..

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    privileged: true
    entrypoint: ["/bin/sh -c"]
    command: ["ls -lha ~"]
```

but it fails with:

```
docker-compose up -d
ERROR: for junk_nginx_1  Cannot start service nginx: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/bin/sh -c": stat /bin/sh -c: no such file or directory: unknown
```

I thought it was because /bin/sh doesn't exists in the image, but it certainly does. removing the `-c` gives me the following error:

```
# this time the container runs, this is in the container logs.
/bin/sh: 0: Can't open ls -lha ~
```

so `/bin/sh` does exists within the image. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the array form of Compose `command:` and `entrypoint:` (and, similarly, the JSON-array form of Dockerfile `CMD`, `ENTRYPOINT`, and `RUN`), you are responsible for breaking up the input into words.  Each item in the array is a word, just as though it was quoted in the shell, and includes any spaces, punctuation, and other characters.

So when you say

```yaml
entrypoint: ["/bin/sh -c"]
```

That is one word, not a command and its argument, and you are telling the shell to look for an executable program named `sh -c` (including space hyphen c as part of the filename) in the `/bin` directory.  Since that's not there, you get an error.

You shouldn't usually need to override `entrypoint:` in a Compose setup.  In your case, the only shell expansion you need is the home directory `~` but that's not well-defined in Docker.  You should be able to just write

```yaml
command: ls -lha /usr/share/nginx/html
```

or in array form

```yaml
command: ["ls", "-lha", "/usr/share/nginx/html"]
# (or other YAML syntaxes with fewer quotes or more lines)
```

or if you *really* need the `sh -c` wrapper

```yaml
command: /bin/sh -c 'ls -lha ~'
command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "ls -lha ~"]
command:
  - /bin/sh
  - -c
  - >-
      ls -lha ~;
      echo these lines get folded together;
      nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

You're using the stock Docker Hub `nginx` image; also consider whether [`docker-compose run`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/) might be an easier way to run a one-off command

```sh
docker-compose run nginx \
  ls -lha /usr/share/nginx/html
```

If it's your own image, try hard to avoid needing to override `ENTRYPOINT`.  Make `CMD` be a complete command; if you need an `ENTRYPOINT`, a shell script that ends with `exec "$@"` so that it runs the `CMD` is a typical pattern.

Answer (score 1):

See [entrypoint usage](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#entrypoint):

> entrypoint: ["php", "-d", "memory_limit=-1", "vendor/bin/phpunit"]

Also see [command usage](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#command):

> command: ["bundle", "exec", "thin", "-p", "3000"]

So, your error means your syntax not ok, the correct one for you is:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    privileged: true
    entrypoint: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
    command: ["ls", "-lha", "~"]
```

The execution:

```
$ docker-compose up
Creating network "20210812_default" with the default driver
Creating 20210812_nginx_1 ... done
Attaching to 20210812_nginx_1
nginx_1  | bin
nginx_1  | boot
nginx_1  | dev
nginx_1  | docker-entrypoint.d
nginx_1  | docker-entrypoint.sh
nginx_1  | etc
nginx_1  | home
nginx_1  | lib
nginx_1  | lib64
nginx_1  | media
nginx_1  | mnt
nginx_1  | opt
nginx_1  | proc
nginx_1  | root
nginx_1  | run
nginx_1  | sbin
nginx_1  | srv
nginx_1  | sys
nginx_1  | tmp
nginx_1  | usr
nginx_1  | var
20210812_nginx_1 exited with code 0
```